# Unable to perform imwrite an image that I can see with imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using opencv, and I have a frame that I can see using imshow() but when I use imwrite to save it on the disk, I get a black image.

```
 ......  
// frame *= 1/255; even converting the color before writing it didn't help
cv::sqrt(frame,frame);
cv::imwrite("name.tif",frame);
frame *=1/15.96;
imshow("frame",frame); //it works fine 
................
```

anyidea why it isn't working. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you build with TIFF format support (in the CMake options)? Did you try other formats: jpeg, png, bmp...

Comment: yes I did try other format and I save an other frame with the TIFF extension and it works

Comment: what do u mean by it doesnt work? does it throw an error or you get a blank frame?

Comment: I get a blank " a black " frame but what I see is smt else

Comment: Can you please post an example frame image and the operations you do to it before this point?

Comment: btw i think 1/255  == 0 due to integer division. 1.0/255.0 should be better

Answer (score 0):

What you've done here is that you've performed imwrite(), then performed a mathematical operation on frame, and then performed imshow().

Ergo, you're writing and viewing 2 different versions of Mat frame.
If you've verified that the .tiff extension works, then it's possible that sqrt() is resulting in a black frame. Try:

```
cv::sqrt(frame,frame);

frame *=1/15.96;

cv::imwrite("name.tif",frame);
imshow("frame",frame);
```

Now you can be certain that you're writing what you're seeing. If there is still a difference between the two, then try doing the same with other image formats